# How to Implement a dictionary of utf8 ReadOnlySpan<byte>?

Tags: c#, html, dictionary, collections, utf-8

I need to implementation a generic dictionary where keys are UTF8 strings represented by a `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` struct.

The interface of the dictionary should be

```cs
interface IUtf8StringDictionary<T>
{
    void Add(ReadOnlySpan<byte> key, T value);
    bool TryGetValue(ReadOnlySpan<byte> key, out T value);
    bool Remove(ReadOnlySpan<byte> key);
    bool ContainsKey(ReadOnlySpan<byte> key);
    void Clear();
}
```

Because span structs can only exist on stack, I cannot use the standard Dictionary implementation.

What implementation would you suggest based on the following conditions?

- TryGetValue should not allocate any memory
- It should perform at least as fast as a `Dictionary<string, T>`

Comment: This does not appear to be feasible as you'll need to create A) an entire dictionary implementation, and B) a string hashing routine.

My suggestion would be to use a `Dictionary<int, List<KeyValuePair<string,TValue>>>` so that `TryGetValue` could do a HashCode lookup on the `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` and then a manual compare against the strings using a `stackalloc char[]` version of the `key` passed in.

This is currently a suggestion to the API: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/2010